# Calculating percentage in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report in the attached format [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4UzXmbWLTJZalZKOEdJWHE2NVE/view?usp=sharing].

There is a  row group based on the CostCenter so that each individual row of CostCenter is displayed. The problem is I want to calculate the percentage of the individual hours and cost based on their respective total values(last column). But I am not able to do so as I am not able to access the total value (last column) in the Percentage column as Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope.

Please help as to how can I calculate the percentage of the individual fields.

Comment: @user1225352 Can you please help on this?

Comment: Do you mean % of Regular Hours as in [RegularHours] / Sum[RegularHours]?

Comment: Yes. It is [RegularHours] / Sum[RegularHours].